# Android - Bluetooth connection InputStream close crashes my app

Tags: android, exception, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I have an Android application where I connect to a bluetooth device. When I shut the device off, the application tries to disconnect. So I try to close the inputstream the outputstream and the socket. Even though I have a try catch on each close try, the app crashes when it tries to close the inputstream. Any ideas? Code example:

```
private void resetConnection() {
    if (mmInputStream != null) {
        try {
            mmInputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "CANNOT CLOSE InputStream", e);
        }
        mmInputStream = null;
    }

    if (mmOutputStream != null) {
        try {
            mmOutputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "CANNOT CLOSE OutputStream", e);
        }
        mmOutputStream = null;
    }

    if (mmSocket != null) {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "CANNOT CLOSE mmSocket", e);
        }
        mmSocket = null;
    }

}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Show us the stacktrace

Comment: @NikoYuwono Wish there was a strack trace :( . The only thing shown is: 

A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000008 (code=1), thread 10912 (Thread-3466)

Comment: Can you post the code where you call the resetConnection() ?

Comment: @NikoYuwono . Sorry I cannot post the exact part of the code but I can tell you that when I send data to the device, if I get an exception (meaning that the device is not available) then at the catch I call the resetConnection in order to reset everything and start scanning for the device again.

Comment: The crash that you got is a native crash that's why it's not been caught by the try catch so I suspect there is something else causing this crash

Comment: @NikoYuwono Could it be device specific? The app works fine in all other devices I have tested, but it fails only to that Samsung Note 3

Comment: It's possible but I can't confirm it sorry